# Draw inward tick in QwtPlot scaleDraw

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

How can we draw axis tick marks in both inward and outwards? I reimplemented QwtScaleDraw and overrode with drawTick but I don't know how to match the tick position and draw additional line using

```
QwtPainter::drawLine(painter,QPointF,QPointF)
```

I tried :

```
inside Plot::drawItems(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect, const QwtScaleMap map[axisCnt]) const

const QwtScaleMap &map;
for (j = 0; j < majTicks; j++)
{
   y = map.transform(majTickList[j]);
  QwtPainter::drawLine(painter, x, y, x + m_majTickLength, y);
}
```

but the axis margin is not matching with the corners of the out axis, small deviation is coming. I took a screenshot here :

[image]

my complete drawInward

```
    void CustomScaleDraw::draw(QPainter *painter, const QPalette &palette) const
    {


        QwtScaleDraw::draw(painter, palette);


        painter->save();

        QPen pen = painter->pen();
        pen.setColor(palette.color(QPalette::Foreground));
        painter->setPen(pen);

        int majLen = m_pPlotWidget->majorTickLength();
        if (m_majTickStyle >= Both && majLen > 0){
            QList<double> ticks = this->scaleDiv().ticks(QwtScaleDiv::MajorTick);
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)ticks.count(); i++){
                const double v = ticks[i];
                if (this->scaleDiv().contains(v))
                    drawInwardTick(painter, v, majLen);
            }
        }
    }


and 
void CustomScaleDraw::drawInwardTick(QPainter *painter, double value, int len) const
{


    int pw2 = qMin((int)painter->pen().width(), len) / 2;

    QwtScaleMap scaleMap = this->scaleMap();

    QPointF pos = this->pos();

    int majLen = tickLength(QwtScaleDiv::MajorTick);


    const int clw = m_pPlotWidget->lineWidth();
    const int tval = scaleMap.transform(value);

    bool draw = false;
    if ( orientation() == Qt::Vertical ){
        int low = (int)scaleMap.p2() + majLen;
        int high = (int)scaleMap.p1() - majLen;
        if ((tval > low && tval < high) ||
            (tval > high && !m_pPlotWidget->axisEnabled (QwtPlot::xBottom) && !clw) ||
            (tval < low && !m_pPlotWidget->axisEnabled(QwtPlot::xTop) && !clw)) draw = true;
    } else {
        int low = (int)scaleMap.p1() + majLen;
        int high = (int)scaleMap.p2() - majLen;
        if ((tval > low && tval < high) ||
            (tval > high && !m_pPlotWidget->axisEnabled(QwtPlot::yRight) && !clw) ||
            (tval < low && !m_pPlotWidget->axisEnabled(QwtPlot::yLeft) && !clw)) draw = true;
    }

    if (draw){

        switch(alignment()){

            case LeftScale:
            {
                QwtPainter::drawLine(painter, pos.x() + pw2, tval, pos.x() + len, tval);

                break;
            }
            case RightScale:
            {
                QwtPainter::drawLine(painter, pos.x() - pw2, tval, pos.x() - len, tval);
                break;
            }
            case BottomScale:
            {
                QwtPainter::drawLine(painter, tval, pos.y() - pw2, tval, pos.y() - len);
                break;
            }
            case TopScale:
            {
                QwtPainter::drawLine(painter, tval, pos.y() + pw2, tval, pos.y() + len);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
//    QwtPainter::setMetricsMap(metricsMap); // restore metrics map
}
```

my scale setup in QwtPlot.cpp

for (int i = 0; i < QwtPlot::axisCnt; i++)
    {
        QwtScaleWidget *scale = (QwtScaleWidget *) axisWidget(i);

```
    if(scale)
    {
        scale->setMargin(0);

        //the axis title color must be initialized...
        QwtText title = scale->title();
        title.setColor(Qt::black);
        scale->setTitle(title);

        //...same for axis color
        QPalette pal = scale->palette();
        pal.setColor(QPalette::Foreground, QColor(Qt::black));
        scale->setPalette(pal);

        CustomScaleDraw *sd = new CustomScaleDraw(this);
        sd->setTickLength(QwtScaleDiv::MinorTick, m_minTickLength);
        sd->setTickLength(QwtScaleDiv::MediumTick, m_minTickLength);
        sd->setTickLength(QwtScaleDiv::MajorTick, m_majTickLength);

        setAxisScaleDraw(i,sd);

    }
}
plotLayout()->setAlignCanvasToScales( true );
```

m_minTickLength = 5;
  m_majTickLength = 9;

Comment: This looks to me like an off-by-one error, which is causing the rounding to sometimes go to the adjacent pixel. That said, the "right" thing to do (IMO) is create the inside scales using a `QwtPlotScaleItem`.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Holthaus. i am new to qwt so i kindly asking you to elaborate little on reimplementing inside scale of qwtPlotScaleItem or help me give a example link .

Comment: Which of the samples are you using as your starting point? I can try to make an example, but I need a starting point.

Comment: Thank you ver much Mr.Holthaus.i have updated my post with the reimplementation of draw in QwtScaleDraw. the same problem comes here when const int tval = scaleMap.transform(value);

Comment: i have used a simple qwtplot example and overrided the qwtscaleDraw, canvas setUp is  m_pCanvas = new QwtPlotCanvas();
    m_pCanvas->setFrameShadow(QwtPlot::Plain);
    m_pCanvas->setLineWidth(0 );
    m_pCanvas->setPalette( Qt::white );
    m_pCanvas->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

    setCanvas( m_pCanvas ); and axis are default.

Comment: OK, i'll take a look, but it will take me a while to get to it (at least 24 hours).

Comment: no problem Mr.Holthaus.i will wait eagerly  and once again thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the effect of inward-pointed ticks by adding additional scale items to the plot, which have the *opposite* alignment property to what their position would normally require.

This requires *way* less code than a custom painter, and you don't have the alignment issues.

## Output

[image]

## Code

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include <qwt_plot_grid.h>
#include <qwt_plot_layout.h>
#include <qwt_symbol.h>
#include <qwt_legend.h>
#include <qwt_scale_widget.h>
#include <qwt_plot_scaleitem.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    // Enable high-DPI scaling with Qt 5.6+
#if (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,6,0))
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    QwtPlot plot;
    plot.setTitle( "Plot Demo" );
    plot.canvas()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    plot.setStyleSheet("QwtPlot{ border: 0; }");
    plot.canvas()->setStyleSheet("QwtPlotCanvas {border: none; margin: 1; background-color: white;}");
    plot.plotLayout()->setCanvasMargin(0);

    plot.enableAxis(QwtPlot::yLeft);
    plot.enableAxis(QwtPlot::yRight);
    plot.enableAxis(QwtPlot::xBottom);
    plot.enableAxis(QwtPlot::xTop);

    plot.setAxisScale( QwtPlot::yLeft, 0.0, 1000.0 );
    plot.setAxisScale(QwtPlot::yRight, 0.0, 1000.0);
    plot.setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, 0.0, 1000.0);
    plot.setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xTop, 0.0, 1000.0);

    plot.axisWidget(QwtPlot::yLeft)->setMargin(0);
    plot.axisWidget(QwtPlot::yLeft)->setSpacing(0);
    plot.axisWidget(QwtPlot::yRight)->setMargin(0);
    plot.axisWidget(QwtPlot::xBottom)->setMargin(0);
    plot.axisWidget(QwtPlot::xTop)->setMargin(0);

    // create inward pointing ticks, and disable their labels
    // notice the alignment is *opposite* to the position.
    // in production code, don't hardcode the positions obviously.
    QwtPlotScaleItem *yLeftScaleItem = new QwtPlotScaleItem(QwtScaleDraw::RightScale, 0);
    yLeftScaleItem->scaleDraw()->enableComponent(QwtAbstractScaleDraw::Labels, false);
    yLeftScaleItem->attach(&plot);

    QwtPlotScaleItem *yRightScaleItem = new QwtPlotScaleItem(QwtScaleDraw::LeftScale, 1000);
    yRightScaleItem->scaleDraw()->enableComponent(QwtAbstractScaleDraw::Labels, false);
    yRightScaleItem->attach(&plot);

    QwtPlotScaleItem *xBottomScaleItem = new QwtPlotScaleItem(QwtScaleDraw::TopScale, 0);
    xBottomScaleItem->scaleDraw()->enableComponent(QwtAbstractScaleDraw::Labels, false);
    xBottomScaleItem->attach(&plot);

    QwtPlotScaleItem *xTopScaleItem = new QwtPlotScaleItem(QwtScaleDraw::BottomScale, 1000);
    xTopScaleItem->scaleDraw()->enableComponent(QwtAbstractScaleDraw::Labels, false);
    xTopScaleItem->attach(&plot);

    plot.updateCanvasMargins();

    plot.resize( 500, 400 );
    plot.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```